# Built-in PHP exception for when expected array element does not have the correct value?

Tags: php, arrays, exception

Is there an appropriate standard PHP exception which can be used when an array is expected to contain an associative value, which is not correct?

For example, I have a method which takes an array of 'configuration' parameters. Those parameters are validated to check that the required ones are there and that they are of the correct type. If any of the required parameters are incorrect or missing, the exception is thrown.

I was wondering what the most appropriate standard exception would be for this, if one exists at all.

**Note**

- The array key might be missing OR might be present but incorrect value.
- The array values may be of any type.

I'm leaning towards [UnexpectedValueException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)

Comment: Maybe this http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php

Comment: I think InvalidArgumentException is better for when the wrong type is sent (string instead of an integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [DomainException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php), which I believe is the most appropriate.

> Exception thrown if a value does not adhere to a defined valid data domain.

Answer (score 0):

How about `OutOfBoundsException`?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php

> Exception thrown if a value is not a valid key. This represents errors
>   that cannot be detected at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

[BadMethodCallException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) covers the invalid, or missing, arguments of a method call.  This would make the most sense for your example.